# Cube Configuration

Tags: olap, cubes, project-server-2007

On "Cube Configuration" page of Project Server, you have the option to add enterprise fields to the cube as dimensions. When you select the option "Assignment" from the cube drop down, you are given a list of available fields to choose from. However, some of the fields are labeled with a **"R__Assignment"** or **"T__Assignment"** suffix and i can't find any documentation on what they do.

Any help would be appreciated ;).

[alt text http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/9567/cubefieldselect.gif](http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/9567/cubefieldselect.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is really undocumented (as almost everything with the cubes). As far as I could understand it that is an acronym for the link path for the field, T standing for Task and R for Resource. Recall that assignment is a relation between tasks and resources. This only happens in the assignment cube.

I've used any of them randomly with no trouble, so I believe you can just ignore it.